# When are phaser traits run?

Tags: traits, raku

The [`will` phaser trait examples](https://docs.raku.org/language/phasers#index-entry-Phasers__will_trait) show this code:

```
our $h will enter { .rememberit() } will undo { .forgetit() };
```

Which is either misunderstood or simply not a real use case. If it's misunderstood, I would say it `enter`s the block with it's assigned a variable. If it's not a real use case, it calls a method on an undefined variable. This is what seems to happen:

```
our &doing-good will enter {
    say( "running" );
        if Backtrace.new.grep: { .subname  ~~ /bad/ } {
            fail("Not authorized to call this");
        }
};
```

This is simply run when the definition is made, that is, when what exactly is entered? The `MAIN` scope?
This is probably the documentation fault. It's very likely that phaser traits can't really be applied to variables, but above, when it's actually a block, it's not really run; the "phaser" is run when something that's totally independent of the variable definition of value happens, at least in this case. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

The "phaser traits" as you call them, will be run at the same time as other phasers of the same name.

The `will` trait on a variable basically sets up phasers in its surrounding scope, with the variable passed as the only positional parameter.  So

```
my $h will enter { dd $_ };
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
my $h;
ENTER { dd $h }
```

In your example:

```
our &doing-good will enter { ... }
```

you are defining a **variable** `&doing-good` that will be passed to the block that is specified.  In your example, I do not see that variable getting initialized, so the block will receive a `Callable` type object (because that is what `&doing-good` will contain if it is not initialized).

Comment: However, you see that the phaser is run, even if the variable is not initialized. Anyway, if it sets phaser in the surrounding scope, what's that scope for that variable?

Comment: That's because the phaser is about the **BLOCK** it is in.  The `will enter` trait is just syntactic sugar to create a phaser on the block that the variable is defined in, passing the variable to the phaser as a positional argument.  Since the ENTER phaser is run **before** the variable is initialized, you will get the default state of the variable as the argument.

Comment: The scope of the variable is the scope it would be without the `will` trait.  The `will` trait does not change that.  It just executes some code at **compile** time to set up the phaser on the block.  Nothing more, nothing less.  The `will` trait doesn't execute anything else.

Comment: Please note that, as shown in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68590823/891440), the `$h` example prints nothing.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that the `will` trait is exactly the same as a the matching phaser – with the single difference that it has access to the variable as its topic.  Thus the `will enter` and the `ENTER` below are very similar, and both execute when the containing scope is entered.

```
ENTER            { note "ENTER phaser with topic $_.VAR.WHAT.raku()" }
my $a will enter { note "will enter with topic $_.VAR.WHAT.raku()"; $_ = 42 };

note 'main';
note "\$a: $a";
```

which prints:

```
ENTER phaser with topic Scalar                                                                                                
will enter with topic Scalar                                                                                                   
main                                                                                                                           
$a: 42
```

Put differently, there's not a distinct "enter" phase that occurs for the variable; it's just referencing the `ENTER` phase of the containing scope.

Comment: So, even if we're "attaching" a phaser to a variable, other than the topicalization of the variable, it's simply a phaser for the scope the variable is in. Also, the first phaser is not run at all?

Comment: What do you mean with "the first phaser" ?