# Do will traits only apply to objects?

Tags: traits, raku

Again on the tail of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68575795/891440), I'm trying to make a `will` trait work, with this (golfed) code:

```
sub show-value( $a-var ) {
    say "Value of {$a-var.^name} is ", $a-var.gist;
}

sub do-stuff () {
    ENTER { say "Going in"; }
    our $bar will enter { show-value($_) };
    $bar = "baz";
    LEAVE { say "Leaving"; }
}

do-stuff();
```

This simply prints "Going in". It (doesn't) work(s) in the same way if you do it on the global scope. Please note that this is an almost direct implementation of the [documentation example](https://docs.raku.org/language/phasers#index-entry-Phasers__will_trait).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't noted your Rakudo version. It sounds like a bug introduced this year.

[Running the same code using glot.io](https://glot.io/snippets/g0yb87otu6):

```
v2021.02.1
Going in
Value of Any is (Any)
Leaving
```

Comment: Right, it's the last version, 2021.07

Comment: FWIW, I don't think there's a bug.  There is a severe misunderstanding of what the `will` trait actually does.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen you mean the example in the documentation? There's not a lot to work with, you know...

Answer (score 2):

On 2021.07 I get:

```
Going in
Value of Any is (Any)
Leaving
```

A clearer example might be:

```
my $bar will enter { $_ = 42 }
say "bar = $bar";  # bar = 42
```

Comment: Right, I was actually using 2021.06. So it was a regression only on that version?